# KendoUI Grid Reorder

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When a user changes the order of columns in a grid, I was able to capture the new column order, serialize it, and store it.
I just can't figure out how to bring that data back and re-apply it to the grid when the page reloads.

I used the "columReorder"  event to post a service call to store the results.

I've tried a couple ways to bring in columns.
I tried binding to kindo grid "columns" property, but an external web service call doesn't come back in time before the grid renders.
Am I going about this correctly or is there a better way to take a serialized list of columns (that i've saved) and set the order when the grid loads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set up columns AFTER the grid is created. You must pass in the column order to the initializer. Once the grid is created, it won't update the order just by passing in the columns object. So, you're gonna need to post some code, but here's one of my solutions for it...

In my model, I pass the column settings into the view, then I turn columns on and off using that (colSet) object, like this...

```
columns.Bound(c => c.LINE_OF_BUSINESS).Hidden(colSet != null ? ("false" == colSet["LINE_OF_BUSINESS"]) : false)
```

You could change the order of columns that way too - it would be two steps in the view. One step to create the column binding in the GridColumnFactory, then pass that in when you intialize the grid (instead of creating it inside the Columns() method parameter list)

Comment: Thanks...Setting columns through the .bound event was the key!

Comment: Really? That worked? With mine, the DataBound event happened too late.

Comment: Yeah it did.  Maybe because I already defined the schema model?  I did this because I knew what the columns were I just wanted the order to be based on user preferences.

Comment: Awesome... please post the code in your question. This comes up fairly often... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270748/kendo-grid-saving-state-in-columnreorder-event

Answer (score 0):

Sure Jasmine, here is what worked for me.  I have multiple grids on the page and there's a user id hard coded that needs

to be replace, but this should give someone else a start...

`var gridResult = $("#1f2e9791-21e1-4d9a-8b9a-4b08a99fee11 .grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read:
                        {
                            //call api for data
                            url: 'http://localhost:61242/api/meds'
                        }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        //define schema fields
                        fields: {
                            Date: { type: "date" },
                            Medicine: { type: "string" },
                            Dosage: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            reorderable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: false,
            resizable: true,
            //dynamically get the height from the outer container (using gridster)
            height: $("#1f2e9791-21e1-4d9a-8b9a-4b08a99fee11").height() - 30,
            scrollable: true,
            columnReorder: function (e) {
                var that = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    //save columns on reorder
                    SaveColsGrid1(kendo.stringify(that.columns));
                }, 5);
            },
            dataBound: function (e) {
                //retrieve columns
                GetColumns('1f2e9791-21e1-4d9a-8b9a-4b08a99fee11');
            }
        });`

save method, which posts an MVC my MVC controller

`function SaveColsGrid1(data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveColsGrid1")',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: data
            });
        }`

retrieve columns and re-order

`function GetColumns(gridId) {
           var sessionId = $("#inSession").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:61242/api/usercolumn/1|' + gridId,
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: gridId,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data && data.length > 0) {
                        var classname = "#" + gridId + " .grid"
                        var realGrid = $(classname).data("kendoGrid");
                        var visibleIndex = -1;
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var column = data[i];
                            // 1. Set correct order first as visibility and width both depend on this.
                            var existingIndex = -1;
                            if (typeof column.Field !== 'undefined') {
                                existingIndex = findFieldIndex(realGrid, column.Field);
                            }
                            else if (typeof column.commandName !== 'undefined') {
                                existingIndex = findCommandIndex(realGrid, column.commandName);
                            }
                            if (existingIndex > -1 && existingIndex != i) // Different index
                            {   // Need to reorder
                                //alert('hi2');
                                realGrid.reorderColumn(i, realGrid.columns[existingIndex]);
                            }
                            // 2. Set visibility state
                            var isHidden = (typeof column.hidden === 'undefined') ? false : column.hidden;
                            if (isHidden) {
                                realGrid.hideColumn(i);
                            }
                            else {
                                realGrid.showColumn(i);
                                ++visibleIndex;
                            }
                            // 3. Set width
                            var width = (typeof column.width === 'undefined') ? null : column.width;
                            if (width != null) {
                                realGrid.columns[i].width = width; // This sets value, whilst rest redraws
                                realGrid.thead.prev().find('col:eq(' + visibleIndex + ')').width(width);
                                realGrid.table.find('>colgroup col:eq(' + visibleIndex + ')').width(width);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error occured');
                },
            });
        }
        //get column index of the existing item
        function findFieldIndex(realGrid, field) {
            var existingIndex = -1;
            for (var i = 0; i < realGrid.columns.length; i++) {
                if (realGrid.columns[i].field == field) {
                    existingIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return existingIndex;
        }
        function findCommandIndex(realGrid, commandName) {
            //var existingIndex = -1;
            //for(var idx = 0; idx < realGrid.columns.length; ++idx)
            //{
            //    if(typeof realGrid.columns[idx].command !== 'undefined'
            //        && realGrid.columns[idx].command.name == commandName)
            //    {
            //        existingIndex = idx;
            //        break;
            //    }
            //}
            //return existingIndex;
        }
    });`